# Why am I having problems with setInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a novice javascript programmer and I always have trouble with the `setInterval`. W3Schools makes it look so easy but I can never get it to work when i need to. Here I have a span I want to make 'flash'.

```
var id = window.setInterval(function(){
             if($("#span1").css("color") == "red"){
                 $("#span1").css("color","blue");
             }
             else{
                 $("#span1").css("color","red");}
         }, 100);
```

I keep getting a `SYNTAX ERROR: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`. What am I doing wrong here?

NOTE: I know there's some jQuery method that could handle this easily. I'm trying to gain a better understanding of this JS function.

**UPDATE** I fixed the syntax error. (Missing quotation). Now I get an error `undefined`.

Comment: Also, don't use w3schools. See http://w3fools.com

Comment: Oh, stop that, @LeeTaylor -- w3schools is a perfectly useful place to go when you're a novice and need lots of examples without a lot of noise. When he knows what he's doing, THEN you can send him to MDN for boring and verbose technical accuracy.

Comment: NITPICK: `$("#span1")` used over and over again is bad practice. `$("#span1")` is "expensive" look up. Do it once, store it into a variable and reference that variable.

Comment: @epascarello Point taken. Partly the reasoning behind me wanting get a mastery over raw javascript. I want to be able to develop without relying so heavily on jQuery.

Comment: The same thing can be applied to regular JavaScript, you should not have multiple getElementById() lines that look up the same element. Just makes the code run more efficiently. Some thing looking up something in a book. Closing the book, and having to look it up again. Saves time by leaving the book open to that page.

Comment: @Blazemonger I disagree. You want good, correct information, especially if you're just learning.

Comment: @LeeTaylor I agree with you generally. I've w3schools has caused me some head aches but to Blazemonger's point W3school's documentation is clean and easy to access.

Comment: @LeeTaylor Good and correct isn't the same as readable and learnable.  It's like asking high school science students to learn from academic journals. There's a reason "JavaScript: The Good Parts" is more popular than "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide." MDN should be used by beginners as a reference but certainly not as a learning tool.

Comment: @Blazemonger. Spend some time on http://w3fools.com and you'll see that w3schools is riddled with inaccuracies, errors and other oddities. I wouldn't want a teacher like that!

Comment: @LeeTaylor Be assured, you had many teachers like that. You just never found them out....

Comment: @Blazemonger I know I did, however I wasn't in a position to choose where I got my education from...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably copy and pasted the code and it has some bad characters in it. Try re-typing the code manually in a new file.

Side-note, you can make the whole thing a hell of a lot more efficient and reliable:

```
(function() {
    var thespan = document.getElementById('span'),
        toggle = true;
    window.setInterval(function() {
        toggle = !toggle;
        thespan.style.color = toggle ? "red" : "blue";
    },100);
})();
```